# how does a cakePHP controller have a model property built in?

Tags: php, cakephp

If I have a controller as follows.

```
<?php
class LoginController extends AppController{

    public function index(){

    }
}
?>
```

I could access Login model as `$this->Login` . How does the `LoginController` class have access to the `Login` model? We did not define any property named `Login` in the `LoginController` class. How does this happen?

Comment: Please check this link :http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html and read "Blog Tutorial - Adding a layer" this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot
>   find a corresponding file in /app/Model. This also means that if you
>   accidentally name your file wrong (for example, post.php or posts.php
>   instead of Post.php), CakePHP will not recognize any of your settings
>   and will use the defaults instead.

**Model.php**, automatically selects a database table name based on a pluralized lowercase object,The table is required to have at least 'id auto_increment' primary key.

You can see for [cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php)